# PHP : Virtual machines VS __FILE__ resolving symbolic links?

Tags: php, deployment, architecture, virtual-machine

I'm using an existing PHP software which makes extensive usage of the `__FILE__` magic constant, to require the bootstrap files, among other things, example:

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/path/to/config.php';
```

Right now I have several websites on the same server running this software.

All the websites have **copies of the files**, it works, but I would like to centralize the "common" files (classes, controllers, etc...), to:

- reduce the amount of files
- simplify deployments

---

At first, I thought about using symlinks for "common" files, together with simple folders for "specific" files:

```
config
classes -> /path/to/common/classes
controllers -> /path/to/common/controllers
...
```

... but the problem is that `__FILE__` resolves symbolic links

> Since PHP 4.0.2, `__FILE__` always contains an absolute path with symlinks resolved whereas in older versions it contained relative path under some circumstances.

It means everything using the constant would resolve pathes relative to the "common" files, which is not what I want.

I know that I can use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME]`, but I don't want to modify the code of the software I'm using, it would be unmaintainable.

---

Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Maybe using **virtual machines** (one for each website) with some sort of shared folders ? (I'm not an expert at all)

Comment: Surely `__FILE__` would be used only in the non-symlinked files that are loading libraries? Or is that used in also in the libraries you plan to symlink? If the latter is the case, then maybe strip out references to `__FILE__` from the libraries, and use autoloading instead.

Comment: That having been said, you may wish to consider whether this is a good idea. If those libraries are a framework, or some other critical system, what happens if you upgrade ten websites in one go and you have problems? Certainly it should all be tested on non-live envs, but in practice sometimes live problems are found on an upgrade. Thus, if you upgrade them individually, it might be slightly more work, but there is less of a panic if something goes wrong.

Comment: (It might be a good idea to explain your deployment process, in your question please, so people can offer advice accordingly.)